# Tool to Trace an HTML Post Submission?

Tags: html, forms, http-post

Is there a way (or tool) that helps seeing (or logging) exactly what is being sent in an HTML `<FORM METHOD=POST>` in response to clicking a `<INPUT TYPE="submit">` button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox
- [Chrome Developer Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html)
- [Safari Developer Tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html)
- [IE9 Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478)
- [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)
- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, potentially helping many others on different platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.wireshark.org/ 
Works well.  It tracks all network traffic and can process most (all?) protocols.  You should see this as an HTTP request.

Comment: Well, to be fair I believe that fiddler is probably the right answer.  It's specifically tuned for use with HTTP on a request level.  Wireshark deals with things on the packet level and requires some fiddling to get to a request level.

Comment: Perhaps my opinion is colored by the fact that I maintain an HTTP stack and so often have to debug trouble that depends on whether a proxy (or which kind of proxy) is used or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 1):

The Google Chrome Web Tools will allow you to see what was sent in an HTTP request, the post vars, etc.

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/

or if you are a Firefox kind or person:

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: All answers are excellent but I am definitely a Firefox kind of person. Firebug is wonderful. +1 to all but I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use a variety of tools such as Firebug or Developer tools in Chrome\Safari, you can see what is being sent to the server the response headers and body. You would have to "preserver log upon navigation" in Chrome or "persist" in Firebug to see the response.

In chrome it's under the Network tab, in Firebug it's under Net. P.s there are other tools for different browsers, i just use these two the most.